# How to simulate a long-running query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to simulate a long-running query in mssql to test out some kill commands and clean-up operations. The problem is, I cannot figure out a way to keep a query running for a long-time. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
select * from sales1 cross join sales2 cross join sales3 ...
```

The query returns immediately though if I do `cursor.fetchall()` it takes forever to fetch the results.

While that's returning, when I do:

```
cursor.execute("sp_who2 'active'")
```

It doesn't show that query (I suppose because it's already 'executed').

Is there a way to emulate a long-running query with only one table of 100 results?

Comment: start a transaction , run query, don't commit trans....

Comment: @MitchWheat maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I get the same results if I do: `>>> cursor.execute('begin transaction')
>>> cursor.execute('select * from sales cross join sales2 cross join sales3')`. Though maybe the (python) connection wrapper does some stuff around it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The waitfor statement

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql

`waitfor delay '00:01'` will wait for 1 minute

Answer (score 3):

In my company we get alerts on `OPEN` `TRANSACTION`/`LONG QUERY` by users (or even `DBA's`)

So yes, `OPEN TRAN` without `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` will do it, or use `WAITFOR DELAY`